# Recharts how to alingn unit with number?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, recharts

I'm trying to align a unit (MW) with a number in y but they don't be aligned, someone knows a way to do this?

[aligment of the y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOPZY.png)

```
<ResponsiveContainer>
            <ComposedChart data={data?.data}>
              <XAxis
                ticks={[0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 360, 420, 480, 540, 600, 660, 720, 780, 840, 900, 960, 1020, 1080, 1140, 1200, 1260, 1320, 1380]}
                tick={{ fontSize: '12px' }}
                tickFormatter={tick => `${tick / 60}h`}
              />
              <YAxis
                type='number'
                tick={{ fontSize: '12px' }}
                tickCount={11}
                domain={[0, dataMax => Math.ceil(Number(dataMax) / 10000) * 10000]}
                tickFormatter={tick => `${Math.floor(tick).toLocaleString('pt-BR')}`}
                tickMargin={5}
                unit='  MW'
              />
              <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray='3' />
              <Tooltip content={CustomTooltip} />
              <Legend verticalAlign='top' content={CustomLegend} />
              {charts.areas.map(chart => (
                <Area name={chart.name} dataKey={chart.dataKey} stroke={chart.stroke} stackId={chart.stackId} fill={chart.fill} dot={false} strokeWidth={0} fillOpacity={1} type='monotone' />
              ))}
              {charts.lines.map(chart => (
                <Line name={chart.name} dataKey={chart.dataKey} stroke={chart.stroke} dot={false} strokeWidth={2} />
              ))}
            </ComposedChart>
          </ResponsiveContainer>
        )}
      </ChartContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default y-axis size is 60.
You should use the `width` property to display the values correctly

```
<YAxis
  type='number'
  tick={{ fontSize: '12px' }}
  tickCount={11}
  domain={[0, dataMax => Math.ceil(Number(dataMax) / 10000) * 10000]}
  tickFormatter={tick => `${Math.floor(tick).toLocaleString('pt-BR')}`}
  tickMargin={5}
  unit='  MW'
  width={100}
/>
```

Related issue: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/2027